# How to detect either event trigger?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, event-handling

I have a input box with id `#input`. This input box will activate a function when is blur or enter button is press.

How can I combine the two events as one?

```
$('#input')
.keypress(function(e))
.blur(function(event) {
  //Do something
});
```

Answer (score 9):

Use [`bind()`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/). Multiple event types can be bound at once by including each one separated by a space:

```
$('#input').bind('keypress blur', function(event) {
    //Do something
});
```

or you can bind multiple event handlers simultaneously by passing an object of event type/handler pairs:

```
$('#foo').bind({
  keypress : function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if(e.which == 13) { //Detects enter key depressed!
    // do something on keypress 
    }
  },
  blur: function() {
    // do something on blur
  }
});
```

Comment: How about detecting the enter button?

Comment: You would need an event that looked specifically for that key to be pressed as that does not directly relate to any page element.

Comment: The first line of `bind`'s docs: `As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method is the preferred method for attaching event handlers to a document.`

Answer (score 0):

like this:

```
$('#input').on('blur keypress', blurKeyPressHandler);

function blurKeyPressHandler(event) {
    if (event.type == 'keypress') {
        // DO SOMETHING
    }
    else if (event.type == 'blur') {
        // DO SOMETHING ELSE
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that these two event will call a same function?

you can define a function, and call it when the event is triggered.

```
`    function dosth (event) {
    //Do something
    };

    $('#input')
    .keypress(dosth)
    .blur(dosth);
`
```